# How to hard-code legal moves for fast lookup?

Tags: java, arrays, lookup

I have created a gameboard (5x5) and I now want to decide when a move is legal as fast as possible. For example a piece at (0,0) wants to go to (1,1), is that legal? First I tried to find this out with computations but that seemed bothersome. I would like to hard-code the possible moves based on a position on the board and then iterate through all the possible moves to see if they match the destinations of the piece. I have problems getting this on paper. This is what I would like:

```
//game piece is at 0,0 now, decide if 1,1 is legal
Point destination = new Point(1,1);     
destination.findIn(legalMoves[0][0]);
```

The first problem I face is that I don't know how to put a list of possible moves in an array at for example index [0][0]. This must be fairly obvious but I am stuck at this for some time. I would like to create an array in which there is a list of Point objects. So in semi-code: `legalMoves[0][0] = {Point(1,1),Point(0,1),Point(1,0)}`
I am not sure if this is efficient but it makes logically move sense than maybe [[1,1],[0,1],[1,0]] but I am not sold on this.

The second problem I have is that instead of creating the object at every start of the game with an instance variable legalMoves, I would rather have it read from disk. I think that it should be quicker this way? Is the serializable class the way to go?

My 3rd small problem is that for the 25 positions the legal moves are unbalanced. Some have 8 possible legal moves, others have 3. Maybe this is not a problem at all.

Comment: How do you calculate the legal moves? Maybe what you're trying to do is unnecessary premature optimisation.

Comment: The game-board is unbalanced. It's from the game BagChal in which you can always move horizontally and vertically but not always diagonally. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Empty_Alquerque_board.svg/250px-Empty_Alquerque_board.svg.png

Comment: It looks like if the difference in x or y coordinate is more than one, or if the new point has a negative coordinate then it will be illegal, otherwise it's legal.  EDIT: Also, if coordinate is odd row and even column, then you can't move diagonally.

Comment: Right @NeplatnyUdaj, this strongly smells premature optimization.

Comment: Could something like a `Map<Point, Set<Point>> mapFromPointToSetOfLegalDestinations` be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a structure that will give you the candidate for a given point, i.e. `Point -> List<Point>`.

Typically, I would go for a `Map<Point, List<Point>>`.

You can initialise this structure statically at program start or dynamically when needing. For instance, here I use 2 helpers arrays that contains the possible translations from a point, and these will yield the *neighbours* of the point.

```
// (-1  1) (0  1) (1  1)
// (-1  0) (----) (1  0)
// (-1 -1) (0 -1) (1 -1)
// from (1 0) anti-clockwise:
static int[] xOffset = {1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,0,1};
static int[] yOffset = {0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1};
```

The following `Map` contains the actual neighbours for a `Point` with a function that compute, store and return these neighbours. You can choose to initialise all neighbours in one pass, but given the small numbers, I would not think this a problem performance wise.

```
static Map<Point, List<Point>> neighbours = new HashMap<>();

static List<Point> getNeighbours(Point a) {
    List<Point> nb = neighbours.get(a);
    if (nb == null) {
        nb = new ArrayList<>(xOffset.length); // size the list
        for (int i=0; i < xOffset.length; i++) {
            int x = a.getX() + xOffset[i];
            int y = a.getY() + yOffset[i];
            if (x>=0 && y>=0 && x < 5 && y < 5) {
                nb.add(new Point(x, y));
            }
        }
        neighbours.put(a, nb);
    }
    return nb;
}
```

Now checking a legal move is a matter of finding the point in the neighbours:

```
static boolean isLegalMove(Point from, Point to) {
    boolean legal = false;
    for (Point p : getNeighbours(from)) {
        if (p.equals(to)) {
            legal = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return legal;
}
```

Note: the class `Point` must define `equals()` and `hashCode()` for the map to behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

> The first problem I face is that I don't know how to put a list of possible moves in an array at for example index `[0][0]`

Since the board is 2D, and the number of legal moves could generally be more than one, you would end up with a 3D data structure:

```
Point legalMoves[][][] = new legalMoves[5][5][];
legalMoves[0][0] = new Point[] {Point(1,1),Point(0,1),Point(1,0)};
```

> instead of creating the object at every start of the game with an instance variable `legalMoves`, I would rather have it read from disk. I think that it should be quicker this way? Is the serializable class the way to go?

This cannot be answered without profiling. I cannot imagine that computing legal moves of any kind for a 5x5 board could be so intense computationally as to justify any kind of additional I/O operation.

> for the 25 positions the legal moves are unbalanced. Some have 8 possible legal moves, others have 3. Maybe this is not a problem at all.

This can be handled nicely with a 3D "jagged array" described above, so it is not a problem at all.

Comment: 3D array works, or you could implement a 2D array of lists of `Point`s

Comment: @mstbaum Right, lists may work too, as long as it's legal to use in a foreach loop,